# How to store Facebook access token in private server? - Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android

Tags: android, facebook

I can store access token on my RESTful server with Facebook SDK 2.0 because it has Facebook.getAccessToken() and Facebook.setAccessToken(). Now I want to apply new SDK for my new app. SDK 3.0 doesn't have setAccessToken. How to do?

Ref link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#advanced

Answer (score 1):

If you check out v3.0.2b, there is a new method in the Session class that will allow you to import an access token:

```
openWithImportedAccessToken(String accessToken, Date expirationTime, Date lastRefreshTime, AccessTokenSource accessTokenSource, List permissions, Session.StatusCallback callback)
```

Opens a session based on an existing Facebook access token. You can find more details in the reference docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session

Comment: Is there an example usage of this method?

Comment: Seems like this was answered by you here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13523884/how-do-you-use-the-method-openwithimportedaccesstoken-in-the-new-facebook-sdk